# "Two thread counter model for measuring execution cycles" changes output, if I add code to the (unrelated) print part

Tags: c, performance, x86

The title is somewhat obscure. Here is the explanation:

I have 2 thread model. 1 thread is incrementing a variable inside a busy loop, the other one reads counter `t1`, does the measurement, reads the counter again `t2` and stores the difference in an array for future printing.

> Why are you not using `rdtscp`? It is serializing and it is already built in the hardware as an instruction.

Well, `rdtscp` is not good enough for my measurements. I need a 1-2 cycle resolution for my case.

Here is the pseudo-code of what I have done, and what is my problem:

```
void* counter_thread(void *input){

    uint64_t* p_counter = (uint64_t *)input;
    set affinity();

    while(1)
        (*p_counter)++;
}

int main(){
    setaffinity();
    warmup();
    uint64_t measurements[1000]; // for storing information
    register uint64_t t1,t2;
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i ++){

        mfence();
        t1 = counter;
        // for now, it is empty
        mfence();
        t2 = counter;
        measurements[i] = t2 - t1;
    }

    printf("measurements\n");    
    for(int i = ITER - 20; i < ITER; i++){
        printf("%d:%ld\n",i, measurements[i]);
    }
}
```

So, with this, for two consecutive reads, I find the difference as 9-10. It is good, but I need better accuracy than this.

For now, my problem is not related to getting a better accuracy. My problem is, if I change the code to this:

```
    int main(){
        // all same as above        
        printf("measurements\n");    
        for(int i = ITER - 20; i < ITER; i++){
            printf("%d:%ld\n",i, measurements[i]);
        }
        printf("measurements\n");    
        for(int i = ITER - 20; i < ITER; i++){
            printf("%d:%ld\n",i, measurements[i]);
        }
        printf("measurements\n");    
        for(int i = ITER - 20; i < ITER; i++){
            printf("%d:%ld\n",i, measurements[i]);
        }
    }
```

This gives 50-60 as difference. Why is this the case?

I have disabled `ASLR` to make sure that they are placed to the same or at least very close physical addresses and they will hit same cache's. I am also running on an isolated core (isolated from other user processes, enabled by providing grub parameter: `isolcpu`) to get rid of any noise.

I have checked both of the codes assemblies. They look almost the same:

**Assembly outputs for given sections**

```
    // counter
    0000000000000aaf <J1>:
    aaf:    48 83 00 01             addq   $0x1,(%rax)
    ab3:    eb fa                   jmp    aaf <J1>
    ab5:    90                      nop
    // ...
    // measurement
    c34:    eb 3e                   jmp    c74 <main+0x185>
    c36:    0f ae f0                mfence 
    c39:    48 8b 9d 38 ff ff ff    mov    -0xc8(%rbp),%rbx
    c40:    0f ae f0                mfence 
    c43:    4c 8b a5 38 ff ff ff    mov    -0xc8(%rbp),%r12
    c4a:    8b 85 30 ff ff ff       mov    -0xd0(%rbp),%eax
    c50:    48 98                   cltq   
    // some instructions for storing, which are identical in both cases
    c7b:    42 0f 00 
    c7e:    7e b6                   jle    c36 <main+0x147>
```

**Full code in C**

As a full example, here is my code. Feel free to use it and share your experiences. I am stuck at this point. I have no knowledge about why they give different results.

```
    #define _GNU_SOURCE
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <sched.h> //cpu_set_t , CPU_SET
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <stdint.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <pthread.h> //pthread_t
    #include <errno.h> // EINVAL
    #include <string.h>

    #define ITER 1000
    // I have disabled core 6 and 7 on my computer.
    // They are siblings, they reside in the same physical core.
    #define COUNTER_THREAD 6    
    #define MEASUREMENT_THREAD 7


    void* counter_thread(void *input){

        uint64_t* p_counter = (uint64_t *)input;
        // set affinity
        cpu_set_t cpuset;
        CPU_ZERO(&cpuset);
        CPU_SET(COUNTER_THREAD, &cpuset);

        if(pthread_setaffinity_np(pthread_self(), sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpuset)){
            fprintf(stderr, "Error while setting affinity on counter thread\n");
        }

        // busy loop, same as: 
        // while(1) (*p_counter)++;
        // I am using assembly because of the C code (while(1) stuff
        // might add other instructions between addition and jump
        // I have also tried to copy-paste the addq instruction so that
        // I will have fewer jumps and more add, but again, this is also
        // changes the measurement from 10 to 50. So, whenever I touch the code
        // I get way less accuracy. 
        asm volatile(
            "J1:\n"
            "addq $1, %0\n"
            "jmp J1\n"
            :"+m"(*p_counter)::);

    }

    void warmup(){
        for(volatile int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){}
    }

    int main(){

        uint64_t counter = 0;
        uint64_t* p_counter = &counter;
        pthread_t ctr_tr;
        pthread_create(&ctr_tr, NULL, counter_thread, (void*)p_counter);

        uint64_t* measurements = malloc(sizeof(uint64_t) * (ITER +1));


        // init self thread
        cpu_set_t cpu;
        CPU_ZERO(&cpu);
        CPU_SET(MEASUREMENT_THREAD, &cpu);
        if(pthread_setaffinity_np(pthread_self(), sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpu)){
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not assign affinity measurement thread\n");
        }

        warmup();
        register uint64_t t1,t2;
        for(int i = 0; i < ITER; i ++){

            mfence();
            t1 = counter;

            mfence();
            t2 = counter;
            measurements[i] = t2 - t1;
        }
        // print only last 20
        printf("measurements\n");    
        for(int i = ITER - 20; i < ITER; i++){
            printf("%d:%ld\n",i, measurements[i]);
        }
        for(int i = ITER - 20; i < ITER; i++){
            printf("%d:%ld\n",i, measurements[i]);
        }
        for(int i = ITER - 20; i < ITER; i++){
            printf("%d:%ld\n",i, measurements[i]);
        }
        // used below to kill busy loop, don't know if it still works.
        pthread_cancel(ctr_tr);
        free(measurements);
        return 0;
    }
```

**Compilation**

I am compiling using:
`gcc main.c -O0 -pthread -o main`

**Bonus error I have**
I also have a segmentation fault when main exits. It is related to some allocation that I cannot find. It is not affecting the execution, and it is not my main problem at the moment.

**rdtscp results**

FYI, I also used `rdtscp`. In my machine it gives 108-144 difference for just this loop:

```
        for(int i = 0; i < ITER; i ++){

            mfence();
            asm volatile(
            "rdtscp"
            :"=a"(t1)::"rcx","rdx");

            mfence();
            asm volatile(
            "rdtscp"
            :"=a"(t2)::"rcx","rdx");
            measurements[i] = t2 - t1;
        }
```

**Summary:**

I have two thread model. One thread is running in an infinite loop incrementing a variable. The other one is reading this value `t1`, do a job (for now, it doesn't even do a job), and read the value again `t2`, and store the differences.
I get ~10 difference between two reads.
The problem is, after the loop is done, I am printing the values. If I add more lines of codes after the measurement loop is done, my measurements are messed up (instead of 10, it gives 50).

**Bonus experiment:** 
If I add array access between `t1` and `t2` (like a pseudo measurement function) I can see that the difference between two reads increases to 11 or 12. That is what I want because it adds 1 more instruction (array access) and I can say that the offset for two measurements is 10 cycles and can calculate other experiments according to that. However, I am stuck at a point that, if I add more instructions **after** the measurement, it changes measurement. I need to fix this first.

### EDIT

So, instead of compiling with `O0`, I have compiled using `Os` and it seems that I always get 10 cycles between 2 measurements. My guessing is it is about alignment because `Os` moves the `main()` function above of other functions. Still, I cannot find the best explanation and even though it is the case, I still don't have an answer to my initial question. If I add another print line at the end of the main, the rest of the function stays at the same virtual address, but I still don't get a good result.