# Changing irrelevant part of the function changes papi measurement of branch prediction

Tags: c, optimization, x86, branch-prediction, papi

I am playing with the codes that I found online and I want to try different branch prediction codes to have a better understanding of branch predictors.

CPU is AMD Ryzen 3600.

Basically, what I am doing is in the code below, I am trying to measure a misprediction rate of a given function/code segment. As a pseudo/shortened code, here is what I do:

```
int measurement(int length, int arr){
   r1 = papi_read();
   for(;i<len;){
      if(arr[j]){
         do_sth();
      }
   }
   r2 = papi_read();
   return r2-r1;
}

void warmup(){
    for(volatile int i = 0; i< 10000; i++){
        for(volatile int j = 0; j < 100; j++){} // important line
    }
}

int main() {
   init_papi(); 
   init_others(); //creates arrays, initialize them, etc.
   warmup();
   for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        results[i] = measurement(128, array);
        usleep(1200); // 2nd important line
   }
   print_mispredictions();
}
```

### My setup

- I have isolated the core I am working on so that there is no other user process in that core. I have also isolated the sibling one so that I am full in charge of both of the cores, except there is an interrupt or a routine.
- Previously, I have seen that if I use `sleep` between iterations (as in main function), [the CPU enters a deeper level C-state so the branch prediction units (BHT in this case) resets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59143138/branch-predictor-entries-invalidation-upon-program-finishes/59470308#59470308). This is the explanation of `2nd important line` in the code.

### What I want to see

Without the `sleep` line I am seeing that in each iteration I am having lower and lower misprediction rates. That is because of the branch predictors are learning the pattern in the array.

With the `sleep` line, what I want to achieve is, at each iteration, I should see similar misprediction numbers, as BPU entries are being reset.

### What is the problem

The problem is when I change the warmup line from

```
void warmup(){
    for(volatile int i = 0; i< 10000; i++){
        for(volatile int j = 0; j < 100; j++){}
    }
}
```

to

```
void warmup(){
    for(volatile int i = 0; i< 1000000; i++){ // notice that I have the 
                                              // same amount of iteration
    }
}
```

then the measurements are messed up. I have experienced this kind of issue in [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59312650/two-thread-counter-model-for-measuring-execution-cycles-changes-output-if-i-a), which is never ever answered. Changing a line that is irrelevant to the measurement changes the measurement behavior.

This is my results:

```sh
# With 1 for loop, expected behavior. At every iteration, it is reset to ~ 60
# For 128 if statement, 60 misprediction is 50% guessing.
$ ./exp 
0:73       #iteration count, misprediction count
1:62
2:63
3:21
4:63
...
# With 2 for loops. Unexpected behavior. It should always reset to ~ 60 but it keeps decreasing.
./exp 
0:66
1:18
2:4
3:4
4:1
5:0
6:0
...
```

Putting a `mfence` or `lfence` instruction after the `warmup` doesn't change the result either.

Below, I am putting the whole code in case someone wants to try and/or has an answer for this behavior.

```
#ifndef _GNU_SOURCE
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#endif
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "papi.h"

#define stick_this_thread_to_core(retval, core_id){     \
    int num_cores = sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN);      \
    if (core_id < 0 || core_id >= num_cores)            \
        retval = EINVAL;                                \
    cpu_set_t cpuset;                                   \
    CPU_ZERO(&cpuset);                                  \
    CPU_SET(core_id, &cpuset);                          \
    retval = pthread_setaffinity_np(pthread_self(), sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpuset);\
}


#define ERROR_RETURN(retval) {                                              \
    fprintf(stderr, "Error %d, (%s) %s:line %d: \n", retval,PAPI_strerror(retval), __FILE__,__LINE__);  \
    exit(retval);                                                           \
}

void papi_my_native_add_event(int* EventSet1, char* eventname, int *native){
    int retval;
    //printf("native add\n");
    if((retval = PAPI_event_name_to_code(eventname, native)) != PAPI_OK)
        ERROR_RETURN(retval);
    //printf("native add to_code is successful\n");

    if ((retval = PAPI_add_event(*EventSet1, *native)) != PAPI_OK)
        ERROR_RETURN(retval);
    //printf("native add add_event is successful\n");

    int number = 0;
    if((retval = PAPI_list_events(*EventSet1, NULL, &number)) != PAPI_OK)
        ERROR_RETURN(retval);
    //fprintf(stderr, "Added %d events.\n", number);
}

void papi_my_native_add_start_event(int* EventSet1, char* eventname, int *native){

    papi_my_native_add_event(EventSet1, eventname, native);
    int retval = 0;
    if((retval = PAPI_start(*EventSet1)) != PAPI_OK)
        ERROR_RETURN(retval);

    //printf("START %s\n", eventname);
}

int RNG_SIZE = 128;
uint64_t* rng_arr;
uint64_t dummy;

// 12th core
int cpuid = 11;

// Code from
// https://github.com/lemire/Code-used-on-Daniel-Lemire-s-blog/tree/master/2019/11/05
// acts like a random number generator, but it is deterministic.
static inline uint64_t rng(uint64_t h) {
  h ^= h >> 33;
  h *= UINT64_C(0xff51afd7ed558ccd);
  h ^= h >> 33;
  h *= UINT64_C(0xc4ceb9fe1a85ec53);
  h ^= h >> 33;
  return h;
}

uint64_t measurement(int* EventSet, uint64_t howmany, uint64_t* arr){
    long long reads[2] = {0};
    PAPI_read(*EventSet, &reads[0]);
    for(int j = 0; j < howmany; j++){
        if(arr[j]){
            dummy &= arr[j];
        }
    }
    PAPI_read(*EventSet, &reads[1]);
    return (reads[1] - reads[0]);
}

void precompute_rng(){
    int howmany = RNG_SIZE;
    for(int i = 0; i < RNG_SIZE; i++){
        rng_arr[i] = rng(howmany) &0x1;
        howmany--;
    }
}


int stick_to_core(){
    int retval = 0;
    stick_this_thread_to_core(retval, cpuid);
    if(retval){
        printf("Affinity error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void init_papi(int* EventSet, int cpuid){
    int retval = 0;
    // papi init
    if((retval = PAPI_library_init(PAPI_VER_CURRENT)) != PAPI_VER_CURRENT )
        ERROR_RETURN(retval);

    PAPI_option_t opts1;
    opts1.cpu.cpu_num = cpuid;

    if((retval = PAPI_create_eventset(EventSet)) != PAPI_OK)
        ERROR_RETURN(retval);
    if((retval = PAPI_assign_eventset_component(*EventSet, 0)) != PAPI_OK)
        ERROR_RETURN(retval);
    opts1.cpu.eventset = *EventSet;
    if((retval =PAPI_set_opt(PAPI_CPU_ATTACH, &opts1)) != PAPI_OK)
        ERROR_RETURN(retval);

    char* eventname = "RETIRED_BRANCH_INSTRUCTIONS_MISPREDICTED";
    unsigned int native = 0x0;
    papi_my_native_add_start_event(EventSet, eventname, &native);

}

void warmup(){
    for(volatile int i = 0; i< 100000; i++){
        for(volatile int j = 0; j < 100; j++){} // important line
    }
}


int main() {

    if(stick_to_core()){
        printf("Error on sticking to the core\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int EventSet = PAPI_NULL;
    int* EventSetPtr = &EventSet;
    init_papi(EventSetPtr, cpuid);

    rng_arr = (uint64_t*) malloc(RNG_SIZE * sizeof(uint64_t));
    precompute_rng(cpuid);

    int iter = 4096;
    uint64_t* results = (uint64_t*) malloc(iter * sizeof(uint64_t));
    for(int i = 0; i < iter; i++)
        results[i] = 0;

    warmup();
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        results[i] = measurement(&EventSet, RNG_SIZE, rng_arr);
        usleep(1200);
    }

    // prints
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        printf("%d:%ld\n", i, results[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    free(results);
    return 0;
}
```

### Compile with

`gcc -O0 main.c -lpthread -lpapi -o exp`

Comment: What CPU are you testing this on?  Intel or AMD?  Which microarchitecture?  I wonder if code alignment has anything to do with this.  Changing unrelated code can make two *other* important branches alias or not.

Comment: @PeterCordes I am using an AMD machine, Ryzen2 (3600) series to be exact. The compiler is `gcc 7.4.0`. Since I am using `ASLR` disabled, you can compile with the same settings to see whether 2 branches are aliasing or not (I believe they will give the similar virtual addresses when compiled)

Comment: I have a Skylake CPU so I can't personally test branch aliasing on your CPU to see whether the loop branch aliases with the `if()` branch, even if I did happen to have the same gcc7.4 etc.  You could try adding padding before any of the loops, e.g. `int dummy=0;` and some `dummy++;` statements would take up a few bytes of code-size.

Comment: Anyway, [edit] your question to include that information.